# Rename with Counter using Python

Tags: python

I would like to mention that pretty much all of these answers worked well to controlling what it renames, I wanted to place a check on all that worked, only one answer did not work, but if this helps anyone, they will have 3 out of 4 answers that works

My shared script works great, but it renames everything it finds in the directory so please be careful when using my shared script 
for super large files I use this python

```
import os
# Function to rename multiple files
def main():
   i = 1000
   path="C:/Users/user/Desktop/My Folder/New folder/New folder/"
   for filename in os.listdir(path):
      my_dest ="(" + str(i) + ")" + ".txt"
      my_source =path + filename
      my_dest =path + my_dest
      # rename() function will
      # rename all the files
      os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
      i += 1
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Calling main() function
   main()
```

OK, so I am trying to control the counter to only see txt files, if I have .txt, .jpeg, .mpeg,
everything gets rename, how can I control this to only .txt files

One more problem, when I use this Python counter or a batch counter it flips my file names

Example

```
File_2019.txt - this should be renamed to (1000).txt
FileRecycled_2019.txt - this should be renamed to (1001).txt
```

Outcome

```
FileRecycled_2019.txt - this should be renamed to (1000).txt
File_2019.txt - this should be renamed to (1001).txt
```

When using this method based on filename it flips the order of my files 
It takes it out of alphabetical order

I am working on a solution for the names being flipped once I find it I will share it so if it helps others

OK, so I have a underscore remover batch file, and that fixed the flipping 
and it renames correctly 
for smaller files I will use this

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=_"
Set "Replace= "

For %%a in (*.txt) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

set count=1000
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  set /a count+=1
  ren "%%f" "(!count!).txt"
)
```

Comment: Find files with the txt extension only using glob. Sort the list before renaming sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `pathlib` module

```py
from pathlib import Path
from os import chdir
path = Path.home() / 'desktop' / 'My Folder' / 'New folder' / 'New folder'  # The path to use
to_usenum = 1000  # Start num
alltxt = list(path.glob('*.txt'))  # Getting all the txt files
chdir(path)  # Changing the cwd to the path

for i, txtfile in enumerate(alltxt):
    to_usename = f"({to_usenum+i}).txt"  # The name to use
    txtfile.rename(to_usename)
```

The `pathlib` module comes in handy when it comes to files handling. The `os` module was used in the code to change the current working directory to the `path`'s location because the renamed file will be placed in the current working directory.

Comment: is there a way to give vote on everyone that worked?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the filename has .txt before renaming.

```py
if filename.endswith(".txt"):
    os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
    i += 1
```

On the filenames, you haven't specified an order for the names. You could use `for filename in sorted(os.listdir(path)):` to move through in alphabetical order.

My solution would be:

```py
import os
import glob

def main():
    path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/My Folder/New folder/New folder/"
    suffix = '.txt'
    files = glob.glob(path + '*' + suffix)
    for idx, filename in enumerate(sorted(files)):
        os.rename(
            filename,
            os.path.join(path, f"({1000 + idx})" + suffix)
        )

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This uses `glob` to get all file paths in the folder with `.txt` suffix. It also uses `enumerate` to count each file rather than having to count the `i` value yourself. The file name is generated using an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python).

Comment: my list of file names are in abc order, when I change the names the names flip. example flyguy_2019.txt and flyguyRecycled_2019.txt name that have recycled must follow after the name without that

Comment: when ever I edit this with anything it fails

Comment: Thanks every but nothing seems to be working

Comment: What errors are you getting? It's hard to help with little information. The filename `flyguy_2019.txt` will always be after the file `flyguyRecycled_2019.txt` when sorted as the characters they depart on `R` vs. `_` have sort values of 82 and 95, respectively. You can check this in Python using `ord`. For example, `ord('R')` returns 82. you might be looking to sort by something else like time created but that would be a separate question.

Comment: yes that is what happens the files with Recycled in the filename always comes first, and I have been looking for a way to make it come after the first name without the word Recycled, I have tried on batch as well and I get the same results.. I will try the ord('R')

Answer (score 1):

I solved it an easy way:

```
import os
# Function to rename multiple files
def main():
   i = 1000
   path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/My Folder/New folder/New folder/'
   for filename in os.listdir(path):
      my_dest = f'({str(i)}).txt'
      my_dest = path + my_dest
      my_source = path + filename
      ext = my_source.split('.')[-1]
      if ext == 'txt':
          os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
          i += 1
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Calling main() function
   main()
```

Comment: Thank you all offered answers worked - but I still have the names flipping - I will update my question a little better for the second problem I have - I just saw chsws explain why they flip

Comment: @JavierRivas Thanks. I tried to use easy and simple things.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion would be to use glob, give it a go

```
import os
import glob
# Function to rename multiple files
def main():
    i = 1000
    path="C:/Users/user/Desktop/My Folder/New folder/New folder/"
    files = glob.glob(path + '*.txt')
    for filename in files:
        my_dest ="(" + str(i) + ")" + ".txt"
        my_source =path + filename
        my_dest =path + my_dest
        # rename() function will
        # rename all the files
        os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
        i += 1
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Calling main() function
   main()
```

this will search for any file name ending with txt extension

Comment: OK I tested and nothing happen `for filename in os.listdir(path):` without this it fails

Comment: Hello let me know if you can help me find a work around this

Comment: This code is the only one that did not work, did not rename